# Object not rendering when passing object to a child component

Tags: vuejs3

I am passing an Typescript object to a child component, but it doesn't seem that the JSON response is correctly mapped to the TS object.

Child Component

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const props = defineProps(
    ['course']
);

console.log(props.course.title); <---- undefined

const router = useRouter();

const showDetails = () => {
    router.push({name: 'courseDetails'})
}

</script>
```

Parent

```
const courses = ref([]);

api.getAllCourses().then(c => courses.value = c)

</script>

<template>
    <div class="flex grid-cols-2 justify-start">
        <div class="">
            <Filter/>
        </div>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 h-4 md:w-4/5 p-4">
            <div class="md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-1 col-gap-2 md:col-gap-8 md:row-gap-10" v-for='(course, index) in courses'>
                <Course :key="index" :course="course"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

api axios call...

```
export const api = {

    async getAllCourses(): Promise<Course[]> {
        const res = await request.get<Course[]>("/v1/courses");

        console.log(res.data)

        return res.data

    },

}
```

ts model

```
interface Course {
    objectId: string;
    id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    lessons: string;
    duration: string;
    course_details: {
        title: string;
        instructor: string;
        introduction: string;
        learn: string;
        topics: string;
        prerequisites: string;
        goal: string;
        additionalDetails: string;
        highLevelOverview: string;
    };
}
```

---

JSON response from server.. snippet

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "objectId": "649419c9e26f71024a0d5901",
            "id": "",
            "title": "Go Algorithms",
            "description": "An awesome GO course",
            "lessons": "5",
            "duration": "7 hours",
            "course_details": {
                "title": "",
                "instructor": "Mike",
                "introduction": "",
                "learn": "Lets do this",
                "topics": "foo, bar, yes",
                "prerequisites": "basic golang skills",
                "goal": "write some code",
                "additionalDetails": "",
                "highLevelOverview": ""
            }
        },
        .....
    ],
    "metadata": "none"
}
```

[image]

Reading the documentation it appears to be correct. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: we need your `courses` variable

Comment: I'm guessing `course` is fetched asychronously, in which case your initial prop value is undefined. the console.log runs before the fetch is complete so prints `undefined`.  once the fetch is done, the value updates and the component works.  You can use a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) to watch for course to have some value before console logging.  The equivalent strategy in the template is to use `v-if="course"` to delay rendering until course has a value.

Comment: @yoduh thank you for posting and I add more to the post, hopefully it helps. A course ts object is passed into it via a for-loop, so it should contain an initilized object. I added `v-if` in the course component just to see if it has any effect, which it did not.

Comment: without your `courses` variable structure it's not possible to help you. maybe a course in your courses doesn't contain `title` property.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev the data is there. I will add a screenshot

Comment: @Mike3355 typescript has nothing to do with the runtime. i wonder why don't step debug it, should be obvious where error happens, otherwise the whole project' source code is needed to debug myself, the problem could anywhere in other files

Comment: The `key` should be on the `v-for`, not on the inner element. Other than that, your code seems fine. If you need more help, instead of offering rep, consider providing a *runnable* [mcve]. Use codesandbox.io (or similar) and replace your axios call with a promise returning data with the same structure as in the actual app.

Comment: What exactly is `request` in your `api` constant? Is it an alias for `axios`? Or are you, by any chance, unwrapping `data` twice? Once In `request` and once in `api`? Details like this are the reason why code should be runnable, therefore debuggable.

Comment: @Mike3355 Can you please try `watchEffect` API ?